# Hartl's Ruby on Rails / Hello_App / Heroku Error H10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have coded the very simple app titled "Hello_App" from Hartl's Ruby on Rails. I followed all Hartl's instructions very closely. Everything worked fine locally. But when I attempted to deploy the app using Heroku, it crashed. I am stumped and don't know where to start.

Part of the Heroku log with H10 errors appears below. **At your request, I have added more from Heroku log.**

```
2015-08-14T19:55:56.904410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-08-14T19:55:56.889764+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-08-14T20:05:25.919515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=1beaad1e-a07e-4d0c-9529-e4a9989b7fd5 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:05:26.640952+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=7f9b2df4-a493-4187-ac15-45d4ff35b61a fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:05:27.086774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=33c8f879-dfd8-4f7c-85f6-2172a7c08b78 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:05:38.952685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=ce43f182-4fff-4165-ad3b-23cb5a68ac13 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:05:39.279391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=96e37351-3ac1-45f0-89ee-54adc829f53e fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:05:39.676755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=4024e8b2-a27d-4fe3-aa49-3e7b128cf0da fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:05:41.312964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=92c17cfa-506d-4c18-a663-b3a04ab83c99 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:05:41.657395+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=a7c6d25a-50cb-4a35-9073-4fddd9d575a4 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:05:41.968456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=1728d5eb-61f2-4467-837d-06d82170269c fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:06:19.817216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=924bc3af-a0a6-4f65-b98a-8218e0cea25b fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:07:04.947791+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=0eb2022f-767e-4f09-a051-58918ccfaf78 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:07:05.409107+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=23d3549c-4f28-4acf-9292-2121140258c1 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:07:05.364009+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=f3ed4b18-f7a8-4bc3-9db6-4891a99f8841 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:20:37.715136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=92983800-f1ad-49a7-b62b-ce72ce8f98cf fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:20:47.198875+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=a04cd8ef-b431-4017-8f35-cb6a628c8edd fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:20:57.600588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=feb42ed2-d19a-49e0-a5b3-9e7e1929a1c4 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:20:58.091505+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=1a7f818c-3de5-4c59-9455-52eef5462f19 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:20:58.349130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=b573207f-0313-4f91-833e-72a28295aa9a fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:21:01.210478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=b025e36f-2001-4b24-a6aa-1ff66095ba42 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:21:01.650946+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=805b2fde-00f7-41df-b080-61aa2127121c fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-14T20:21:01.943160+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-scrubland-1831.herokuapp.com request_id=5e6e6d4f-836e-43fa-813d-8f09f7627f10 fwd="67.244.72.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Also, when I keyed "$ git push heroku master" prior to deployment, I got the following the following warnings, though I'm not sure they are relevant to the crash.

```
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform     features
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
remote:        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
remote:        ruby '2.0.0'
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
```

Can anyone give me some basic suggestions? Please remember in any replies that I am very new to all of this.

Comment: Can you post more of the log?

Answer (score 0):

Puts this in you Gemfile

```
group :production do 
  gem 'pg' #sqlite3 gem is not supported on Heroku.
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

run `bundle` commit the changes and try to push to heroku again `git push heroku master`

Comment: Great suggestion @Luis.  I added the following to my gemfile: group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

Comment: BTW, the error was mine. Hartl said to do the above--but I somehow missed this instruction.